# how to view single image with respect to particular ID value using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my code overall image has been viewed but i need only particular ID value image should be displayed..

```
<div class="photo">
    @foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/ComapnyLogo"), "*.png"))
    {
        var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
        <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/ComapnyLogo/{0}", img.Name))" />
    }
</div>
```

hidden id

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.hdnCompany" id="hdnCompany" />
```

[image]

```
public ActionResult ViewCompany()
        {
            var data = dp.Company.SqlQuery("Select * from CompanyRegistration").ToList();
            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: If you only want one image, why are you iterating through all of them?  What value is stored in the hidden field?  Is it just the Id?  Can you make an image path with _just_ the Id?

Comment: @maccettura i have saved the image by using session ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake i cleared the problem

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/ComapnyLogo/" + MainModel.CompanyID + ".png"))" />
```

In this code is working fine in my side..